# Excel VBA: If cell starts with "2", then save to directory

Tags: excel, vba

I have some worksheets I need to save to separate directories dependent on a numbering system found in cell A10.

If the number in A10 starts with a "2", it needs to be saved one place, if it starts with anything else it can be saved to a second destination.

I have made the save functions on hotkeys, but can't seem to get a INTR function to work properly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If left(Range("A10"),1) = 2 then
  Activeworkbook.saveas Path1 & FileName
else
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Path2 & FileName
End If
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly! Any idea on how to make it loop for all open files or loop for a specific folder of workbooks?

Comment: Glad I could help! That's great fodder for a new question, or better yet, a search here at SO or the web in general. I know there are more than a few questions here that show looping through a directory. `FileSystemObject` is what you want to look for. Also, it helps the community if you click the check mark on the answer that solved your problem.

Comment: Thanks! I've checked off your answer, and I'll do a search for looping.

Answer (score 0):

You can chane the folder where  you want to save your files in the following manner:

```
 If Left(Range("A10").Value,1) = 2 then
     ChDir MainFolder
 Else
     ChDir OtherFolder
 End If
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Gradesbook_File
```

Comment: If Range("A10").Value = 2, I don't think this will work as the cell value is "201456000". I need something that determines just the first character = 2

Comment: OK, I edited the code for it to pick up th first digit